# Problema ao ler arquivo json usando PHP

Tags: php, json

Estou tentando, salvar e buscar informações dentro de um arquivo json usando php, o meu problema é que quando adiciono mais de um registro no arquivo, quando uso **json_decode** me é retornado **null**.  Quero saber se o problema está acontecendo quando eu insiro os dados, ou se é quando eu lendo esses dados.

conteúdo do users.json:

```
{"usuarios":{"username":"Lucas","data":"30\/04\/19"}},{"usuarios":{"username":"csa","data":"30\/04\/19"}}
```

Classe responsável por pegar as informações

```
<?php

// Essa classe tem 2 funçoes salvar o usuario ou retornar os dados do usuario
class serverControl{
    private $path;

    public function __construct(){
        $path = dirname(__FILE__) . '\\';
        $this->path = $path;
    }

    public function buscaDados($arq){
        if(empty($arq)):
            return 'Erro parametros passados são invalidos';
        endif;

        $arq = $this->path . $arq . '.json';

        if(!file_exists($arq)):
            return 'Erro arquivo '.$arq.' não pode ser lido ou não exite';
        endif;

        $arq = file_get_contents($arq);

        $arqArray = json_decode($arq, true);

        return $arqArray;
    }

    public function salvarDados($d, $i,$arq){
        if(empty($d) & empty($i) & empty($arq)):
            return 'Erro Parametros passados são invalidos';
        endif;

        $arq = $this->path . $arq . '.json';

        if (!file_exists($arq)):
            return 'O arquivo '.$arq .' a ser modificado não exite';
        endif;

        // Adiciona o identificador
        $dados = array($i => $d);

        // Tranforma o array $dados_identificador em JSON
        $dados_json = json_encode($dados);

        // "a" indicar que o arquivo é aberto para ser escrito
        $fp = fopen($arq, "a");

        // Escreve o conteúdo JSON no arquivo
        $escreve = fwrite($fp, $dados_json);

        // Fecha o arquivo
        fclose($fp);
        return true;
    }
}
```

Comment: Esse JSON não é valido... o que vem nesse $i => $d?

Comment: O identificador usuarios

Answer (score 0, accepted):

De acordo com o comentário do colega, o JSON é inválido. Como ele é um array, está faltando as [], o correto seria:

```js
[{"usuarios":{"username":"Lucas","data":"30\/04\/19"}},{"usuarios":{"username":"csa","data":"30\/04\/19"}}]
```

Aqui tem um exemplo:

```html
<?php
$variavel = '{"usuarios":{"username":"Lucas","data":"30\/04\/19"}},{"usuarios":{"username":"csa","data":"30\/04\/19"}}';
$arqArray = json_decode($variavel, true);
echo ('teste 1<br>');
print_r($arqArray);
echo ('<hr>');

$variavel2 = '[{"usuarios":{"username":"Lucas","data":"30\/04\/19"}},{"usuarios":{"username":"csa","data":"30\/04\/19"}}]';
$arqArray2 = json_decode($variavel2, true);
echo ('teste 2<br>');
print_r($arqArray2);
echo ('<hr>');
?>
```

O "teste1" retorna vazio, e o "teste2", já com a alteração, retorna os dados

Uma dica: Para validar se o seu JSON é válido, você pode usar um validador online, aqui tem um exemplo:

http://json.parser.online.fr